# Char Array in PreProcessor

Tags: c-preprocessor

I need to define an array, that later on will be the name of a class, and will be pointed to.

For example (in a non pre-processor way):

`const char *button_names[4]={"b0","b1","b2","b3"};`

and later on (when it will be define in pre-processor), in a function it will be called as :

`static Button2 button_names[i]`

How can I define it that array to be in pre-processor?

**Edit2:**

```
Button2 *Buttons[8] = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}; // Here I use an optional up to 8 Buttons.
```

and later on, after I read parameter file: i get the `numSW`

/* Below example is only to check if I can use such technique - I know it is not a good coding. Example here is only for up to 4 Buttons*/

```
void init_buttons()
{
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numSW; i++)
        {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                        static Button2 bt1;
                        Buttons[i] = &bt1;
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                        static Button2 bt2;
                        Buttons[i] = &bt2;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                        static Button2 bt3;
                        Buttons[i] = &bt3;
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                        static Button2 bt4;
                        Buttons[i] = &bt4;
                }

                Buttons[i]->begin(buttonPins[i]);
                if (buttonTypes[i] == 0) /* On-Off Switch */
                {
                        Buttons[i]->setPressedHandler(OnOffSW_ON_handler);
                        Buttons[i]->setReleasedHandler(OnOffSW_OFF_handler);
                }
                else if (buttonTypes[i] == 1) /* Momentary press */
                {
                        Buttons[i]->setPressedHandler(toggle_handle);
                }
                Buttons[i]->setID(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some background on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @EdgarBonet - Well it is complicated... I do not want to hard code the number of Button/ Relays each board have. it can be a dual relay, and possibly up to 16 relays on-board.

The amount of Buttons/Relay are stored in a paramter file which obviously read after all classes have been defined and created. So .... see edit 2 in a sec.

Comment: I cannot see the usefulness of these preprocessor macros.Please, explain **what** you are trying to achieve rather than **how** (e.g. with the preprocessor) you think you may achieve it. So far this looks like an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @EdgarBonet I hope Edit 2 is clearing that up

Comment: My main goal is to be able to define, not in code but reading from a paramter file, the number of instances of `Button2` I need, since I want to use same code, for 2,4,8,16 Relays board.

Comment: use dynamic allocation with `new`

Comment: @Juraj I hope I explained my self right :( .... did you understand my main goal ?- Can you exaplin with an example how `new` solves it? ?

Comment: @Juraj Thank you- it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
void init_buttons()
{

        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numSW; i++)
        {
                Buttons[i] = new Button2;   // <--- **Thnx to Juraj**!!!
                Buttons[i]->begin(buttonPins[i]);
                if (buttonTypes[i] == 0) /* On-Off Switch */
                {
                        Buttons[i]->setPressedHandler(OnOffSW_ON_handler);
                        Buttons[i]->setReleasedHandler(OnOffSW_OFF_handler);
                }
                else if (buttonTypes[i] == 1) /* Momentary press */
                {
                        Buttons[i]->setPressedHandler(toggle_handle);
                }
                Buttons[i]->setID(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: why not  `Button2* buttons = new Button2[numSW];`? then you can do `buttons[i].begin()`

Comment: I need `Buttons[]` to be defined at the beginning of code, meaning "global" (to have access to instances). I define it inside a function, since that was I can use `nunSW` that was read from parameter file in flash.

Comment: sorry, yes, in setup() `buttons = new Button2[numSW];` while `Button2* buttons;` is global